# How to use (char)167 or § in wildcard. C# find and replace

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, wildcard, office-interop

I am making VSTO app. And I am using FindAndReplace function. For finding patterns. But I cant use §. It doesent work.

I tried

```
char K = (char)167;
string[] nimed = new string[] {$@"<({K}) ([0-9])>", , @"<([1-5])[-^~]([0-9]{2})[-^~]([0-9]{1;6})>"}
```

It finds second pattern but not first. But if I will change § on something else, then it works.

```
 Word.Range FindAndReplace(Word.Range rngToSearch, object findText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            bool found = false; //options
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = true;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = false;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;                      //Function for searching and wrapping the text. It can also replace the wraped text.
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = false;
            object wrap = 1;
            //execute find and replace
            found = rngToSearch.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
            if (!found)
            {
                rngToSearch = null;
            }

            return rngToSearch;
        }
        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {


            char K = (char)167;
            string[] nimed = new string[] {@"<(3)[-]([1-4])[-^~]([1-4])[-^~]([0-9]{1;3})?([0-9]{2})>", @"<([1-5])[-^~]([0-9]{2})[-^~]([0-9]{1;6})>", @"<([1-5])[-]([0-9]{2})[-^~]([0-9]{1;6})/([0-9]{1;4})>", $@"<({K}) ([0-9])>" };
            Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\install\CSharp\tulemus.txt", $"Char is: {K}" + Environment.NewLine); //returns § so K is right char
            Word.Range rng = doc.Content;
            foreach (string nimi in nimed)
            {
                if (FindAndReplace(rng, $"{ nimi}", "") != null) { 
                while (FindAndReplace(rng, $"{ nimi}", "") != null)
                {
                    Word.Range f = FindAndReplace(rng, $"{ nimi}", "");

                    FindAndReplace2(rng, $"{ nimi}", f.Text.Replace((char)45, (char)160). Replace((char)32, (char)30));



                }}

            }

        }
```

There is no error messages. it just doesent search. But If I try it manually in Word, then it works. How can I make § searchable in C# Wildcards.

The sample text what I am trying to search is:

> § 5

And actually it should work like this: `@"<(§) ([0-9])>"`

Comment: I added more info to my question. If I will search manually with Wildcard for `(§) ([0-9])` it will work. but in C# it doesn't.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that a manual search for <(§) ([0-9)]> actually matches "§ 5" ? I ask because Word that match does not work here, nor does <§, because Word's Find does not seem to regard § as a character that can begin a Word. (It can be confusing because Find/Replace see Words in the same way as MS Word's Range.Words collection, i.e. in that collection, a § character is regarded as a Word).

Comment: I agree with @yokki. The pattern works when § is the first character in the document, but not otherwise. This pattern - `[ ^013]§ ([0-9])>` - works when the character is preceded by a space or paragraph mark, but won't find the first character in the document nor if the character is the first one in a table cell. This - `§ ([0-9])>` - works for all instances, but doen't differentiate whether anything precedes the character. I think you'll need to use this last, then determine what the character immediately preceding the found range is...

Comment: Thank you guys. `§ ([0-9])>` is what I am looking for. Now it seems very obvious.

Comment: Can you please reply to your own question and mark your reply as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. `§ ([0-9])>` is what I am looking for. Now it seems very obvious.